# .NET Console StandardOutput does not return input "question"

Tags: vb.net, console, redirectstandardoutput

I am trying to completely intercept a console application, that is, grabbing it's output, and inserting the input.

So far, I can pretty much grab the output, and input is completely perfect.
However, it will not show the "prefix"/"question" of the console's output, until you send some input.

As an example, when hooking to the CMD.exe console. When you regularly start it up in Windows, you get something like this:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
>   Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Username>

However, the output only returns:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
>   Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

And then when you insert something like "D:" (to go to the D:\ disk), you get the following:

> C:\Users\Username>D:

And that's it. Doesn't give you "D:\>" either, starting the cycle all over again.

This is my current code, however, I am 99% sure there's nothing wrong with it. It works perfectly except for this.

```
Class MainWindow

Private MainDispatcher As System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    StartProcess("cmd.exe")
End Sub

Private Sub InputTB_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles InputTB.KeyUp
    If e.Key = System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter Then
        InputStream.WriteLine(InputTB.Text)
        InputTB.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private InputStream As IO.StreamWriter
Private OutputStream As IO.StreamReader
Public ProcessToMonitor As New Process
Private Sub StartProcess(ByVal FileName As String)

    ProcessToMonitor = New Process
    ProcessToMonitor.StartInfo.FileName = FileName
    ProcessToMonitor.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    ProcessToMonitor.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    ProcessToMonitor.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    ProcessToMonitor.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    ProcessToMonitor.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = False
    ProcessToMonitor.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

    ProcessToMonitor.Start()

    InputStream = ProcessToMonitor.StandardInput
    OutputStream = ProcessToMonitor.StandardOutput

    ConstantReadThread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Lowest
    ConstantReadThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub OutputReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs)
    MainDispatcher.Invoke(New WriteOutputDelegate(AddressOf WriteOutput), e.Data)
End Sub

Private ConstantReadThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ConstantRead)
Private Sub ConstantRead()
    Do
        MainDispatcher.Invoke(New WriteOutputDelegate(AddressOf WriteOutput), OutputStream.ReadLine())
    Loop
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub WriteOutputDelegate(ByVal Text As String)
Private Sub WriteOutput(ByVal Text As String)
    OutputTB.Text &= Text & vbNewLine
    OutputTB.ScrollToEnd()
End Sub
```

End Class

I also know about the "OutputDataReceived", which is what I used at first, which had the same problems, that's why I stepped over to the read loop, I know it's more CPU consuming.

And as always, any help much appreciated.

-René

P.S. Solutions/suggestions in C#.Net also accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can get the extra data you are looking for, since that is generated through "CMD" as an application itself. I believe the functionality you are trying to receive is not even output to the output stream.

This may be because Windows adds this extra functionality to every single console application it launches, and is not something the application actually sends out as an output stream.

What I suggest you do is to figure out the default path CMD starts out in (appears to be the equivalent of):

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
```

You can use that to simulate the same functionality.

If you wish to know where CMD checks for applications and so forth, see the environment variables on your system, more specifically the "PATH" environment variable.